# finding .exe without known path, Microsoft Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to resize some images with the Imagemagick tool. To use this tool, it's obvious that it should be installed on the PC. But this is not always the case, so befor resizing the images, the script should check, if imagemagick is installed. If it's not installed, the batch file is installing an already downloaded version of Imagemagick.

```
:start

if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe" goto found

goto notfound

:notfound
    echo magick.exe was not found
    cd %~dp0\im_setup
    ImageMagick-7.0.8-14-Q16-x64-dll /SP /SILENT /NORESTART /NOICONS
    goto start
goto end


:found
    echo magick.exe was found
    cd %~dp0\Pictures
    "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe" mogrify -resize 1250X833 *.JPG
goto end


:end
```

Right now everything works out quite well, **but**
if a user has installed an older or newer version of ImageMagick, the batch file don't find the magick.exe bc the folder name is different. All in all it's an unclean solution.

*Is there a way, the batch file finds the magick.exe its self?*

Comment: `dir /b /s /a "c:\program files\magick.exe" "c:\program files (x86)\magick.exe"`. This is how to search. Use `For /f` to parse. Errorlevel is 1 if nothing found.

Comment: I'm new to batch and i have to admit I only copied some code together to get the code above to work. I'm not sure how to  implement your advise. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /s /a "c:\program files\magick.exe" "c:\program files (x86)\magick.exe"
If errorlevel 1 ImageMagick-7.0.8-14-Q16-x64-dll /SP /SILENT /NORESTART /NOICONS
If errorlevel 0 echo Do nothing
```

Get the general idea, similar to what you are doing. See `if /?` and `dir /?`.

Comment: First of all thank you,
I tried it now, but somehow both cases get activated. Is it bc the dir search in more than one folder, and so there are multiple error-level? I don't get it, why both error codes can be activated at the same time. (i changed the install with an echo for testing puropose)